# Wpf - problem with binding to a collection item

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding

this is my simple xaml that shows in a textbox the age of the first person in a collection of persons. I don't understand I after click the age isn't changing.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="132*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="179*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Persons[0].Age}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Change Age</Button>
</Grid>
```

this is the code behind of the xaml:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public MainWindow() {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons.Add(new Person{Age = -1});

        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        (Persons[0] as Person).Age = 5;
    }
}
```

this is class person:

```
 public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Age"));
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Your code worked fine for me when I pasted it into a WPF project in Visual Studio 2010 just now. What version of WPF and Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Worked just fine for me to. Copy/Paste to project and it works like a charm. If you set a breakpoint in set for Age, does it fire PropertyChanged or is it null?

Answer (score 1):

that's probably because the view don't catch that one property of one element of the list changed. It only catches that the list changed (add or remove elements)

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    (Persons[0] as Person).Age = 5;
    Person p = Persons.First();
    Persons.Remove(0);
    Persons.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: But this shouldn't be necessary because the Person class itself implements INotifyPropertyChange. (Indeed, the original code works just fine on my system.) All that's happening here is that an individual Person object's Age property is changing - list level notifications aren't even necessary. In fact when I replace ObservableCollection<Person> with List<Person>, it continues to work - the property change notifications that Person is raising are working correctly.

Comment: The Person object is probably sending the INotifyPropertyChange. But you're not binding to the Person, you're binding to the first item of an ObservableCollection, so it only catches adds or removes from the Collection.

Comment: You could do something where each `Person` gets a PropertyChange event attached that triggers the `Persons` collection changed event

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your class so all should be good.

Are you sure its not changing ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked perfectly for me. I even changed the button click handler so I could keep clicking and see the TextBlock update.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (Persons[0] as Person).Age = (Persons[0] as Person).Age + 1;
}
```